# C# Web API Returning 404 Error With Certain Files

Tags: post, iis, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I have a web API endpoint called `SaveEstimate` which is returning a 404 error when certain data is POSTed.  Based on research I did, I was originally thinking it was because of the file size.  However, the file is less than 2MB and in my `web.config` file I have the following settings:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="26214400" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="26214400" />
```

The data being posted is the file (as a Base64 encoded string) along with some JSON data.  I've tried setting up various logging in both IIS and in my site (to write to a file and SQL database), however this error is not being caught anywhere I can find.

If I do the test with a different (smaller) file, than the request completes successfully.  This leads me to believe it has something to do with the file size but, unless I misunderstand the `web.config` settings, they should allow a request up to about 25 MB.  Is there another setting I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any guidance/help you can provide.

Comment: Learn the sub status code first, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: As far as I know, 404 error is page not found, that means your request may not send to the web api. I suggest you could firstly check the request url is right. Then I suggest you could post some codes about the web api controller and how you send the request for us to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these step it worked.

https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb306.aspx

1. Modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config
2. Edit the request filtering feature settings and the request limits using IIS manager
3. Manually edit the ApplicationHost.config file